# can I get the battery usage accurate enough to 0.1%

Tags: android, battery

I want to calculate the power consumption of my app when it finished running on my android phone.

I know the api of BaterryManager.Level but it can only feed me the 1% usage of my battery.I must run my app as long as hours to get the battery level change in a obvious level.Can I get the 0.1% level of battery usage so I can calculate the power consumption accurate?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can get any useful information at that level. There are other activities going on in your phone that also consume power, even if nothing else is running, such as OS services. 0.1% is probably in the noise. Also, since your app consumes so little power, it is probably spending a lot of time in an idle state (blocked or sleeping). I suspect that even if you were to run it for hours, you are not measuring your app so much as background activity.

Here's my suggestion:

1. Find the part of your app that is likely to consume power, either directly (processing intensive) or indirectly (e.g. Wifi, GPS).
2. Compile and run that core part in its own test program.
3. Run as many of those test programs in parallel that you can.

Make sure you also get a power consumption baseline, meaning find out the power consumption of the phone when you are not running anything.

By the way, given that your app is already using little power, you many not have to worry about the power consumption.